# Using Jersey for non-restful calls

Tags: jersey

Is it ok to have Jersey handle all requests not just rest-related ones? Including session based. Or are there any performance, threading, etc considerations? Jersey/Resteasy hava a lot of convenience functionality provided that would be nice to use compared to just plain servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works for any HTTP-based communication.